# Theme parsing error with evince

Tags: 18.04, themes, gtk, evince

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed. Every time I used evince to view a pdf file, I get the following error on my terminal:

> Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening  file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory

The error has no obvious negative consequences, it is just annoying to see error message on the terminal all the time.

Is there a package providing the missing theme? Or how can I get rid of this error?

P.S. I found that there is an installable package named `gnome-builder`, but installing it with `sudo apt-get install gnome-builder` does not provide the missing `.css` file.

Comment: You could also delete the offending line on `gnome-builder.css` to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is bugs occurring in new 18.04 release, please refer to this link to follow-up the issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/1773045.

There are already (temporary) fix to make the message/warning disappear, please run following command on terminal:

```
cd /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps
sudo ln -s gedit.css gnome-builder.css
```

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/1773045/comments/3

Comment: Good to see that this one is fixed now.